# How do I get puppet master to listen on IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, ruby, puppetmaster, rvm, rhel7

So I have a RHEL 7 server on an internal network with IPv6, and I am able to SSH into it via IPv6 and it is also serving DNS to other hosts over IPv6.

I have noticed that puppet master bind to IPv4 only:

```
$ netstat -n -l | grep 8140
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8140            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

A quick Google reveals that it is most likely that ruby on RHEL 7 are compiled without IPv6 support.

So I just get it up and running with IPv4 for now.

Having everything else running on IPv6 though, I wonder what's the best way to get puppet master to listen on IPv6? Can I install ruby from the upstream rpms with IPv6 turned on? Or install a separate IPv6 enabled ruby environment via rvm, but then how would I get puppet to use the one provided by rvm?

Comment: Is this open source Puppet or Puppet Enterprise? And what version?

Comment: Open source puppet installed from puppetlab repo at 3.7.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Puppet Enterprise the puppetmaster should be listening on a dual stack IPv6/IPv4 socket by default. Though PE has [some other IPv6-related brokenness](http://www.ringingliberty.com/2015/03/31/making-puppet-enterprise-3-7-work-with-ipv6/) (my site) you'll have to work around.

In open source Puppet, such as you may have obtained via EPEL, you need to set the `bindaddress` explicitly in the `[main]` section of `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`:

```
[main]
bindaddress = ::
```

which by default will bind to a dual stack socket and accept IPv6 and IPv4 connections from anywhere.

Comment: Oh!! To show how that my Google fu has failed! Thank you that worked! Now I got the following, does that mean it is IPv6 only?

    netstat -n -l | grep 8140                  \n

    tcp6       0      0 :::8140                 :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: Nope, it's a dual stack socket and accepts IPv4 and IPv6 connections.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Is it even possible to tell the difference between a dual stack socket and a v6-only socket from the netstat output?

Comment: @kasperd As far as I can tell, netstat doesn't distinguish. I simply tested them with netcat. :)